# UIScrollview delegate not getting called when number of cells is small

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have manually created one refresh like feature in a `collectionView`. The feature works using the scrollview's delegate method `willBeginDrag/didenddrag`  etc. But when the `collectionView's` number of items is less, these delegate methods are not getting invoked (The `collectionView` doesn't scroll at all).

I want to know whether there is anyway such that the `scrollview` delegate methods will be called irrespective of the number of items that the collection view holds??

Comment: But it scrolls on the screen right? The cells are moving? Maybe there is nothing to scroll, and the bouncing (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces) is not the same as scrolling?

Comment: Have you tried adding `pan gesture` to scroll view

Comment: @Johannes: I have enabled vertical bouncing in the xib.. Still it does't scroll at all.. unless there are enough contents in the collection view.